# How to link windows in Debian Gnome?

Tags: debian, gnome3, window-manager

There are many solutions to link things in one figure in applications. 
However, I would like to link windows in Gebian Gnome

1. open one window etc from Gnome Overview/...
2. the second window opens at the same time

I am thinking if such procedure is technically is possible in Debian and Gnome. 
I would like to create such a procedure etc in MATLAB.

Currently, I am just programmatically organising windows to different locations initially when created.

OS: Debian 8.5 64 bit
Window manager: Gnome 3.14
Linux kernel: 4.6 backports
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
Client app where wanted to apply: MATLAB 2016b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can be a future feature in the coming release, but it cannot be reached itself in Gnome 3.14 now. 
Next Gnome release is coming at about Q1 of 2017. 
I think it can help the situation.